# Can I install virtualenv on USB Disk?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'd I like to install virtualenv on an USB disk so that i can use it also on other computers. How can I do it? Just creating a virtualenv on the disk doesn't seem to work...

I'm using Mac and the target computer has Fedora.

Comment: You'll probably have to install the *Python* interpreter used to create the *VEnv* on that disk too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39000975/create-a-virutalenv-on-another-drive-access-is-denied

Comment: @CristiFati Probably I didn't explained well. `virtualenv` creates correctly the directory and it works fine on my computer, but it does not work on other computer

Comment: Virtualenvs are not meant to be movable. Why not just pip freeze and recreate it on the target machine, like everyone else?

Comment: [virtualenvs aren't portable](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+relocatable). They're a development tool but not a distribution/deployment tool.

Comment: @NilsWerner The target machine is the computer of physic lab in my university, where pip and virtualenv aren't installed, so I can't recreate it

Comment: @phd Oh this is not good :(, do you know how can I create a virtualenv directly on the target computer if it hasn't `virtualenv` and `pip`?

Comment: Yes, "doesn't seem to work" is not good enough. Check [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Python 3.4+ have [ensurepip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html) and [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) built in.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it using Winpython

Check out this answer:
[Using Virtualenv with Winpython from flash drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37074148/using-virtualenv-with-winpython-from-flash-drive)

**edit based on the update about MacOs on comments**

You can install using anaconda using silent [install mode](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/macos.html)
That was taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45140556/4288795
The answer is for windows, but it should be adaptable to MacOs using the link above

Good luck on your projects!

Comment: I'm using Mac and the target computer has Fedora

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer is YES but of no use.**

The internal architecture used in Virtualenv, hard codes all the paths as absolute paths in multiple places. Most notably all the files in the "site-packages" folder contain hard coded paths and many or most of them are in ascii format. So there is no normal means to change them to a relative paths.

It may however work in a very restricted set of situation like if you can maintain the same folder path in all the computers and same family of os etc etc. But and its a really big 'but' whether even in this scenario it will work smoothly.

**Unless there is vendor support from its architecture level you cannot get true portability.**

> ***Using pip-freeze with "requirements" file and recreating the
> virtualenv on all systems separately is the only option available as
> of now.***